# Json structure for highcharts with PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json, highcharts, structure

I would like to retrieve the same JSON structure used to run a Highcharts graphic ([demonstration site here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/yaxis-plotlines/)):

```
?'([
[Date.UTC(2013,5,2),0.7695],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,3),0.7648],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,4),0.7645],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,5),0.7638],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,6),0.7549],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,7),0.7562],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,9),0.7574],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,10),0.7543],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,11),0.7510],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,12),0.7498],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,13),0.7477],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,14),0.7492],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,16),0.7487],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,17),0.7480],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,18),0.7466],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,19),0.7521],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,20),0.7564],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,21),0.7621],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,23),0.7630],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,24),0.7623],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,25),0.7644],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,26),0.7685],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,27),0.7671],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,28),0.7687],
```

I retrieve my SQL data on my database in the data.php file:

```
$sth = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT date_insert, valeur FROM mesure_bac where type_capteur='TEMPERATURE'and id_bac='".$id_bac."'");

$rows = array();

while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {

  $rows['data'][] = $r;

}


$result = array();
array_push($result,$rows);


print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Only, the execution result JSON gives me the following structure:

```
[{"data":[{"date_insert":"2017-07-06 15:05:17","valeur":25},{"date_insert":"2017-07-06 15:07:16","valeur":25},{"date_insert":"2017-07-06 15:16:50","valeur":25},{"date_insert":"2017-07-06 15:27:00","valeur":25},{"date_insert":"2017-07-06 15:37:09","valeur":24},{"date_insert":"2017-07-06 15:47:18","valeur":25},{"date_insert":"2017-07-06 15:57:27","valeur":25},{"date_insert":"2017-07-06 16:07:37","valeur":25},{"date_insert":"2017-07-06 16:17:46","valeur":25},{"date_insert":"2017-07-06 16:27:55","valeur":25},{"date_insert":"2017-07-06 16:38:04","valeur":25},{"date_insert":"2017-07-06 16:48:14","valeur":25},{"date_insert":"2017-07-06 16:58:23","valeur":25},{"date_insert":"2017-07-06 17:08:32","valeur":25},{"date_insert":"2017-07-06 17:18:41","valeur":25},{"date_insert":"2017-07-06 17:28:51","valeur":25},{"date_insert":"2017-07-06 17:39:00","valeur":25},{"date_insert":"2017-07-06 17:49:09","valeur":25},{"date_insert":"2017-07-06 17:59:18","valeur":25},{"date_insert":"2017-07-06 18:09:28","valeur":26},{"date_insert":"2017-07-06 18:19:37","valeur":26},{"date_insert":"2017-07-06 18:29:46","valeur":25},{"date_insert":"2017-07-06 18:39:55","valeur":26},{"date_insert":"2017-07-06 18:50:05","valeur":26},{"date_insert":"2017-07-06 19:00:14","valeur":26},{"date_insert":"2017-07-06 19:10:23","valeur":25},{"date_insert":"2017-07-06 19:20:32","valeur":25},{"date_insert":"2017-07-06 19:30:42","valeur":25},
```

What are the php transformations to perform the same JSON data structure as the demonstration?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the structure yourself. This should do the job

```
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $rows['data'][] = array(
        "Date.UTC(" . str_replace('-', ',', $r['date_insert']) . ")",
        $r['valeur']
    );
}
```

Comment: Do you have an idea of the problem of my last answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a simple `parsing` also on JavaScript side. Take a look at the example below.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/o226yvvv/